# how to get google friend list

Tags: android, google-plus

i am trying to get the Google plus circle friend list with the  below  URL

https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{userid}/people/visible?key={apikey}

but found the below error

```
{
 "error": {`enter code here`
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured"
 }
}
```

Comment: Looks like access is not configured.  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-ajax-search-api/kaKYuUstwB0

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have not used the API Console to indicate that your app requires access to the Google+ API. See https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/ and the "Before you Begin" section for the steps you need to go through.

In particular, see steps 3 and 4 regarding how to get the client ID from the API console.

Comment: i am facing the problem how i will get the Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0. Google console return the client id or secret id when i press the create the OAuth  id button

Comment: To just see it work, the API Explorer might help: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.list?userId=me&collection=visible&_h=2& - make sure to turn on the Authorize requests button.

Comment: yes i know to turn on the button but my question is how i will get the key in my code or if this key exist in api console where it exist

Comment: Answer clarified, but see Joanna's answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note that people.list can only be called on an authenticated user. You can include the API Console client ID when configuring your Google+ Sign-In button, if the trouble is coming from the API Console set up. However, a user will have to log in to your app before you can request their list of Circled people. This is because when they log in, they control which Circles are shared with your app, and your app receives the flat list of users--without Circle names.